Template code not showing in Django template file despite moving from base.html to sports.html
I have a Django project where I initially wrote all the HTML and template code in the base.html file. However, as my project grew, I decided to organize my templates better by moving specific code to separate template files. I created a new template file named sports.html and copied the relevant code from  base.html to sports.html. However, when I view the sports.html page in my browser, I only see the contents of base.html being rendered, and the code I moved to sports.html does not appear.
Here's the structure of my base.html file:
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Head content here -->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header, sidebar, footer content here -->
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
    <!-- Footer content here -->
</body>
</html>

Here's the structure of my sports.html file:
{% extends 'BTXApp/base.html' %}

{% block content %}     

<!-- My content code goes here -->     
<!-- But it's not showing up in the rendered page -->

{% endblock %}

I have double-checked the paths and the configuration in my Django settings, and everything seems to be correct. I can see the code perfectly fine in my text editor (Sublime Text), but it is not rendered in the browser.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Show us your file tree structure.

C:\Users\rion\BTX\templates\BTXApp\base.html and other templates

C:\Users\rion\BTX\templates\BTXApp\base.html looks incorrect. Usually temple are in project/appname/templates/base.html structure.

If you want to extend from a template in your template folder in your project you should only write base.html and in your settings.py write like this:
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        .
.
.
            ],
        },
    },
]```
you should have templates folder in your project folder like this:(if your Django project named A) A/templates/base.html
even after this, your app's template structure should be like this: (yourappname)/templates/(yourappname)/(the place for your templates related to this app)

